# Where to use synchronized methods in C# : Interfaces or implementations?

Tags: c#, multithreading, interface

We are having an interface for a logger application, and it could have different implementations. Being a logger, the objects of implementations can be shared among multiple modules and thus needs synchronization.

I am using this code to make a method synchronized: `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`

My query is: if I use this annotation within interface, would it make all the implementations synchronized? OR, would I need to put this annotation within specific implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does no good on the interface, because `MethodImplAttribute` is itself marked `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited = false`

But this is an anti-pattern anyway, the documentation says

> Locking on the instance or on the type, as with the `Synchronized` flag, is not recommended for public types, because code other than your own can take locks on public types and instances. This might cause deadlocks or other synchronization problems.

Instead implementations should lock (if not internally threadsafe) on an instance of `object` which is `private` to the class.

The problems of declarative synchronization are well-known -- it leads to lock order inversions -- and so the recommendation against using it is universal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity on inheritance flag. But not sure about deadlock because a deadlock happens when we use nested synchronization. If I am providing a synchronized method, how is it supposed to create a deadlock, unless on until I am calling some other synchronized method from it?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal: Calling a synchronized method while a lock is held is enough to trigger a deadlock if another thread takes the locks in a different order, it can happen even if the synchronized method doesn't call more synchronized methods.  Because declarative synchronization works on the object, you can't control whether another thread takes the same lock.  That's why locking on a private object solves the problem -- you can be sure no one else's code takes the same lock.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal: At this point it should be clear that being able to mark the interface and automatically gain the behavior in all implementors would be terrible -- the implementor wouldn't know to avoid nested locks, and implementations implemented with concurrent collections would pay for unnecessary locking.

Comment: Completely agree with the second point. First one is still doubtful to me. Although the object on which lock is being obtained is different. But, two synchronized methods and two non-synchronized methods with complete synchronized blocks should be same. I would experiment a few things before making any conclusions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` is an old idea that turned out to be quite bad.

If you look at the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions(v=vs.110).aspx), you will see that

> **Static methods lock on the type, whereas instance methods lock on the
>   instance.**

So since you you are using an interface and as it is already pointed out that `MethodImplAttribute` is marked with `AttributeUsageAttribute.Inherited = false` therefore you implementation is going to lock on to `this`, which is accepted as a very bad pattern that ends up with deadlocks.